# Clarification of "avoid if-else" advice

Tags: coding-style, readability, conditions

The experts in clean code advise not to use `if/else` since it's creating an unreadable code. They suggest rather using `IF` and not to wait till the end of a method without real need.

Now, this `if/else` advice confuses me. Do they say that I should not use `if/else` **at all (!)** or to avoid `if/else` nesting?

Also, if they refer to the nesting of `if/else`, should I not do even a single nesting or I should limit it to max 2 nestings (as some recommends)?

When I say single nesting, I mean this:

```
    if (...) {

        if (...) {

        } else {

        }

    } else {

    }
```

**EDIT**

Also tools like Resharper will suggest reformatting `if/else` statements. It usually concerts them to `if` stand-alone statement, and sometimes even to ternary expression.

Comment: If one runs FindBugs on a large code base (not mine!), some of the mechanically findable errors stem indeed from these if-statements. However just moving code to their own method might hamper readability too. _The code style must fit._

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elegant ways to handle if(if else) else](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122485/elegant-ways-to-handle-ifif-else-else) and of [How to tackle a 'branched' arrow head anti-pattern?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205803/how-to-tackle-a-branched-arrow-head-anti-pattern)

Comment: If any so called experts tell you not to use "if/else" at all then they are exactly the type of expert I would simply ignore.

Comment: @Ramhound Some of the eminent experts and tools suggest reformatting if/else. Look at my edit.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think this advice came from a software metric which called *Cyclomatic complexity* or *Conditional complexity* check [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)

Definition:

> The cyclomatic complexity of a section of source code is the count of
>   the number of linearly independent paths through the source code. For
>   instance, if the source code contained no decision points such as IF
>   statements or FOR loops, the complexity would be 1, since there is
>   only a single path through the code. If the code had a single IF
>   statement containing a single condition there would be two paths
>   through the code, one path where the IF statement is evaluated as TRUE
>   and one path where the IF statement is evaluated as FALSE.

So

> Do they say that I should not use if/else at all (!) or to avoid
>   if/else nesting?

No you shouldn't avoid if/else at all! but you should be careful about Cyclomatic complexity of your code. More code complexity tends to have more defects. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702/whats-your-a-good-limit-for-cyclomatic-complexity) the right limit would be **11**. A tool called Code Complete categorize the score like that [Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364946/what-is-the-highest-cyclomatic-complexity-of-any-function-you-maintain-and-how):

- **0-5** - the routine is probably fine
- **6-10** - start to think about ways to simplify the routine
- **10+** - break part of the routine into a second routine and call it
  from the first  routine

**How to calculate Cyclomatic complexity "basically":**

From example [here](http://testingwarrior.blogspot.com/2011/12/cyclomatic-complexity-with-example.html):
consider the following pseudo code :

```
if (A=354) {

    if (B>C) {/*decision 1*/ A=B} else {/*decision 2*/ A=C}

   }/*decision 3 , in case A is NOT equal 354*/ 
print A
```

please note that this metric is concerned about number of decision in your program/code so from the code above we could say that we have 3 decisions ( 3 values of A)

let's calculate it formally so consider the following control flow of the code: 
[image]

The complexity M is then defined* as:[Ref](http://www.literateprogramming.com/mccabe.pdf)

```
M = E − N + 2P
```

where

```
E = the number of edges of the graph
N = the number of nodes of the graph
P = the number of connected components (exit nodes).
```

by applying the formula `E(flow lines) = 8` , `N (nodes)= 7` , `P (exit nodes) =1`
then `M = 8-7 + (2*1) = 3`

*there is also another definition stated but it is close :`M = E − N + P` check the [reference](http://www.literateprogramming.com/mccabe.pdf) for theory.

Please note that many of [static code analysis tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) could calculate the Cyclomatic complexity of your code.

Comment: Remember that the cost of a method call can be significant, depending on the language. There's almost always a tradeoff between writing readable code and writing performant code. It probably won't make an appreciable difference, and "premature optimization is the root of all evil", but it could have a significant effect if you threw in a loop structure around this whole thing, or if the code were itself in a recursive pattern.

Comment: functions/methods with cyclomatic coplexity less than 10 are not even worth looking at - unless your code is scoring 95% at sonar, have 100% unit test coverage, etc. But CC over 20 is a red flag - you must refactor that asap.

Comment: If you really want bad/unreadable code, follow the cyclomatic complexity rubbish for something like `switch(myEnumType)`.

Comment: So how would you write the code to reduce the cyclomatic complexity then?

Answer (score 78):

IMO, the previous answers focus on edge cases and code which should be rewritten anyway. Here are some cases I see nearly everywhere in which `if/else` should have been replaced by `if` or another language construct.

Note: I make the answer community wiki. Feel free to modify it and add other examples of cases where `if/else` usually leads to bad code.

Beginners, [ye be warned](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Pirates_Ye_Be_Warned_sign)! `if/else` has a potential of creating an unreadable code when not used carefully. The next examples show the most common cases where `if/else` is easily misused.

### 1. Guard clause

I stopped counting how many times I've seen something like this:

```cs
void Demo(...)
{
    if (ok_to_continue)
    {
        ... // 20 lines here.
    }
    else
    {
        throw new SomeException();
    }
}
```

Nobody needs extra indentation. The same code could have been written like this:

```cs
void Demo(...)
{
    if (!ok_to_continue)
    {
        throw new SomeException();
    }

    ... // No indentation for the next 20 lines.
}
```

**Rule: if you can remove an `else` statement by inverting the `if` check, handling an error, and exiting immediately, (else otherwise continue on), then do so.**

### 2. Code duplication

This one is also quite frequent.

```cs
if (!this.useAlternatePanel)
{
    currentInput = this.defaultTextBox.Text;
    bool missingInput = currentInput.Length == 0;
    this.defaultProcessButton.Enabled = !missingInput;
    this.defaultMissingInputHelpLabel.Visible = missingInput;
}
else
{
    currentInput = this.alternateTextBox.Text;
    bool missingInput = currentInput.Length == 0;
    this.alternateProcessButton.Enabled = !missingInput;
    this.alternateMissingInputHelpLabel.Visible = missingInput;
}
```

This is an excellent example of beginners' code, because a beginner wouldn't always see how such code can be refactored. One of the ways is to create a map of controls:

```cs
var defaultControls = new CountriesProcessingControls(
    this.defaultTextBox,
    this.defaultProcessButton,
    this.defaultMissingInputHelpLabel);

var alternateControls = new CountriesProcessingControls(
    this.alternateTextBox,
    this.alternateProcessButton,
    this.alternateMissingInputHelpLabel);

void RefreshCountriesControls(CountriesProcessingControls controls)
{
    currentInput = controls.textBox.Text;
    bool missingInput = currentInput.Length == 0;
    controls.processButton.Enabled = !missingInput;
    controls.missingInputHelpLabel.Visible = missingInput;
}

RefreshCountriesControls(this.useAlternatePanel ? alternateControls : defaultControls);
```

**Rule: if the block in `else` is nearly identical to the block in `if`, you're doing it wrong and causing code duplication.**

### 3. Trying to do two things

The opposite is also common:

```cs
if (...)
{
    foreach (var dateInput = this.selectedDates)
    {
        var isConvertible = convertToDate(dateInput);
        if (!isConvertible)
        {
            this.invalidDates.add(dateInput);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    var languageService = this.initializeLanguageService();
    this.Translated = languageService.translate(this.LastInput);
    if (this.Translated != null)
    {
        this.NotificationScheduler.append(LAST_INPUT_TRANSLATED);
    }
}
```

The block within `if` has nothing to do with the block within `else`. Combining two blocks in the same method makes the logic difficult to understand and error-prone. Finding a name for the method, as well as commenting it properly is extremely difficult too.

**Rule: Avoid combining blocks which have nothing in common together in an `if/else` block.**

### 4. Object-oriented programming

This sort of coding is also frequent among beginners:

```cs
// `animal` is either a dog or a cat.
if (animal.IsDog)
{
    animal.EatPedigree();
    animal.Bark();
}
else // The animal is a cat.
{
    animal.EatWhiskas();
    animal.Meow();
}
```

In object-oriented programming, this code shouldn't exist. It should be written like this instead:

```cs
IAnimal animal = ...;
animal.Eat();
animal.MakeSound();
```

given that each class (`Cat : IAnimal` and `Dog : IAnimal`) will have their own implementation of those methods.

**Rule: when doing object-oriented programming, generalize functions (methods) and use inheritance and polymorphism.**

### 5. Assigning a value

I see this one everywhere in codebases written by beginners:

```cs
int price;
if (this.isDiscount)
{
    price = -discount;
}
else
{
    price = unitCost * quantity;
}
```

This is a terrible piece of code, since it's not written for humans.

- It is misleading. It makes you think that the main operation here is the choosing between discount and non-discount mode, while the actual main operation is the assignment of `price`.
- It is error prone. What if later, one condition is changed? What if one of two assignments is removed?
- It invites even worse code. I've seen a lot of pieces like that where `int price` was instead `int price = 0;`, just to get rid of compiler warning if one of the assignments is missing. Hiding warnings instead of solving them is one of the worst things one can do.
- There is a tiny code duplication, which means more characters to type originally, and more changes to do later.
- It's uselessly long.

The same could be written like this:

```cs
int price = this.isDiscount ? -discount : unitCost * quantity;
```

**Rule: use the ternary operator instead of `if/else` blocks for simple value-assignments.**

Comment: -1 for giving dogs Pedigree. +1 for good explanation. if (+1-1==0)==true do nothing;

Comment: #4 is actually pretty fundamental: you can *always* refactor *all* conditionals to polymorphism. Smalltalk is the existence proof of that principle, it doesn't even *have* any conditional construct, there is no `if`, no `else`, no `switch`, no `case` not even loops! Only virtual method dispatch (called *messaging* in Smalltalk). Booleans are actually implemented using the same Church Encoding that is typically used to encode Booleans in Lambda Calculus.

Comment: For someone like me who is new to the world of coding and refactoring, this was as informative as it can be and an eye opener to the mistakes i was committing till now

Comment: Very good examples. However, issue with #2 is that it instantiates an object that is never used, this normally should be avoided.

Comment: @TotalWipeOut: [that's right](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40264595/240613)! This being said, I won't bother too much about an unused variable here. One could get rid of the variable by moving the code inside the ternary operator, but readability would suffer.

Comment: Agree with most points but #5 is only a matter of syntactic sugar, should be left out

Comment: With #5, I feel like it would make more sense to implement `discount` as a float between `0` and `1`. Thus: `float price = unitCost * quantity * (1 - discount);`. If there is no discount (`discount == 0.0`), then the price is unchanged (`* 1`); if the discount is 100% (`discount == 1.0`), then the item is free (`* 0`). It certainly makes a heck of a lot more sense than using a boolean to tell if there's a discount, and then using unnecessary control flow to assign it to a negative value that has nothing to do with the actual price.

Comment: As for #2, I was thinking of a "parent" class before you brought your solution to the table. I.e. a class that abstracts both `default*` and `alternate*` so that the caller can simply use `*` and not have to duplicate code or data--the *superclass* handles all the `default vs alternate` politics. Unless that's what the example is already doing. In either case, the solution isn't optimal.

Comment: I would like to upvote this 10 times. Such a concise answer with great examples of bad code smells

Comment: Rule #1 seems so obvious for everyone that I want to be sure, for me, reading a negative condition is more confusing than if / else statement, in Clean Code they advise to avoid negative conditions. I would prefer to identify quickly the else statement instead of missing a negative condition at the beginning of my method.

Answer (score 9):

I really like what Abdurahman said in his answer.

Another way to look at the “avoiding if/else” statement is to think in terms of decisions.

The objective is to avoid confusion when following code.  When you have multiple if/else statements that are nested, it becomes hard to understand the functions main objective.  The programmer writing the code understands the logic *now*.  BUT, when that same programmer revisits that code a year or two down the road, the understanding is generally forgotten.  A new programmer looking at the code has to be able to identify what is going on.  So the objective is to break complexity up into simple, easy to understand functions.  The objective is not to avoid decisions, but to establish an easy to understand flow of logic.

Comment: +1 for "The programmer writing the code understands the logic now. BUT, when that same programmer revisits that code a year or two down the road, the understanding is generally forgotten". So true.

Answer (score 7):

Code block nesting, aka the "arrowhead" anti-pattern, reduces readability of code because you must either continue shifting to the right, reducing the available width for lines of "real" code on the screen, or you must violate the indenting and other formatting rules that in the normal case make code easier to read.

Case in point:

```
if (X) {
    if (Y) {
       DoXandY();
    } else {
       DoXOnly();
    }
} else {
   DoDefault();
}
```

This is a simple example and I wouldn't have issues with a few levels of this type of nesting, *provided* that the total LOC for this structure was only about a screen long, and that the formatting involved didn't add too much whitespace on the left hand side (consider using 3 or 4 spaces instead of a tabspace, especially if the code will be viewed in other editors where a tabspace may be 8 spaces or more). Beyond that, you may forget or not easily be able to see the initial condition under which the others are nested. This can cause you to get "lost" in your codebase, especially if you have a structure where X and Y are independent:

```
if (X) {
    if (Y) {
       DoXandY();
    } else {
       DoXOnly();
    }
} else {
   if (Y) {
       DoYOnly();
    } else {
       DoDefault();
    }
}
```

In this alternate universe to the OP's specific question, now we have two "if(Y)" condition checks, and if, in a real piece of code, we couldn't see the nested parent condition, we could think we're in a different place in code than we really are, and that causes bugs.

One way to reduce nesting is to distribute the outer condition into the inner conditions. Back to your initial snippet (no "DoYOnly()"), consider the following:

```
if (X && Y) {
    DoXandY();
} else if (X) {
    DoXOnly();
} else {
    DoDefault();
}
```

Look Ma, no nesting! At the cost of an additional evaluation of X (which, if it is computationally complex to evaluate X, you can perform up front and store in a boolean variable), you make the structure a single-level if/else decision tree, and when editing each branch, you know the condition that must be true to enter it. You must still remember what *wasn't* true in order to get to that "else if", but because everything's at the same level it should be easier to identify the previous branches of the decision tree. Alternately, you can remove all the else keywords by testing a more complete version of the condition at every step:

```
if (X && Y) {
    DoXandY();
} 
if (X && !Y) {
    DoXOnly();
} 
if(!X) {
    DoDefault();
}
```

Now you know exactly what must be true for each statement to be executed. However, this starts toeing a line of other readability issues; it becomes harder to see that all of these statements are mutually exclusive (which is part of what an "else" block does for you).

Other ways to include nesting include reversing one or more conditions. If most or all of the code of a function is within an if statement testing a condition, then you can usually save yourself that level of nesting by instead testing that the condition is *not* true, and performing anything you'd do in an else block beyond the original if statement, before returning out of the function. For instance:

```
if(!X) {
    DoDefault();
    return;
}

if(Y) {
    DoXAndY();
} else {
    DoXOnly();
}
```

This behaves the same way as both of the above statements, but only tests each condition once, and has no nested ifs. This pattern is sometimes known as a "guard clause"; the code below the initial if statement will never execute if X is false, so you can say the if statement "guards" the rest of the code (which is why we never need to test that X is true in the rest of the code; if we get to that line, X is true because we would have exited the function early otherwise). The downside is that this doesn't work as well for code that's a smaller part of a larger function. If there were a "DoMoreWork()" function after the entire snippet above, it would have to be included in both the guard clause code and below the remaining conditional statement. Or, the guard clause could be integrated with the remaining code using the "else if" pattern:

```
if(!X) {
    DoDefault();        
} else if(Y) {
    DoXAndY();
} else {
    DoXOnly();
}

DoMoreWork();
```

In this example, DoMoreWork() is always executed even if X is false. Adding the same call below the previous snippet with the return statement would cause DoMoreWork to be called only if X is true, but regardless of whether Y is true or false.

Comment: I read exact the same samples on the net :). Not exact like yours, but they explained it in the same way.

Comment: Your first example has a `DoYOnly();` case which the latter examples are missing.

Comment: That first example is tangential; it doesn't match the format of the OP's snippet and was meant to prove a point about how you could, given conditions that could be independently true, lose your place in a nested codebase and think you're somewhere you're not. Edited to clarify

Comment: Have a hard-time feeling early-return is preferable to if-else. Early return is the cause of so much confusion, wondering why your code is never executed at all or writing code that doesn't take effect. Also nested indentation is a made-up problem stemming from computer terminals in the 80's. It's not an issue anymore. Indentation makes for easy reading so go ahead and indent! Normally though if you have lots of indentation you probably should break something out or do something different anyway.

Comment: @JohnyTex - there is, I think, a difference between "guard clauses" and "early return". Burying a return six levels deep in conditional loops several screens long is a smell. A half dozen or so lines under one level of nesting, performing a default action and getting out, is a valid pattern, much better than enclosing the entire rest of your code in an "else" block.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, the advice may also mean that `if/else` should be substituted with `if/else if` where proper. The latter is more informative and readable (excluding trivial cases of course, like `if (x > 0) else if (x <= 0)`).

`if/else if` has one more advantage than just being more readable (though that is a considerable advantage too). It helps the programmer avoid mistakes in case when there are more than two branches depending on the condition. Such style will make the `missed` case more obvious.

Comment: So you just put the negated condition into the else if? That doesn't seem too DRY to me. And there is also the risk that if you change the condition you forget to change the negated one. I do not like it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason they are advising you to only use `if` statements, and not `else` is to avoid the classic bug of `if this then for everything else do this`. The scope of `else` is difficult to predict.

For example; let's say I am programming the controls for a self-driving car.

```
if (light is red) then {
    stop car
} else {
    drive forward
}
```

While the logic is sound. When the car comes to a yellow light it will keep driving thru the intersection. Likely causing an accident when it should have slowed down and stopped.

Without the `if/else` the logic is less prone to mistakes.

```
if(light is red) then {
  stop car
}
if(light is yellow) then {
  slow down
}
if(light is green) then {
  drive forward
}
```

While my code might not make the best self-driving car. It just demonstrates the difference between an ambiguous condition and explicit conditions. Which is what the author was likely referring too. Don't use `else` to short cut logic.

Comment: good example with car ;)

Comment: In your second example I'd prefer to see those ifs replaced with else-ifs to make it clear that the light states are mutually exclusive. Also, what about a default condition? What if there's a power cut or the lights are broken? Else-ifs would make it easy to add a default else clause.

Comment: @RichSmith yes, I agree, but the point of my answer wasn't the code I wrote. It was to illustrate that the `else` in a if condition includes `everything else`. The scope of `if` is narrow but the scope of `else` is wide.

Comment: I think the second piece of code is horrible actually. A bunch of if-statements on a row. For example red might occur twice because you didn't see that someone wrote it at the top. I would suggest a switch statement.