# Is this a case where 'else' is inevitable?

Tags: clean-code, control-structures, control-flow

I am writing some code that enables / disables a certain kind of hardware function. To enable it on, I have to call some methods, and to disable it, some others.

Of course I want this code to be clean, so I try to keep the use of `if/else` to a minimum. See [Elegant ways to handle if(if else) else](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122485/elegant-ways-to-handle-ifif-else-else) and [Clarification of "avoid if-else" advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206816/clarification-of-avoid-if-else-advice) for discussions about this.

```
void LightTest(bool enable) {
    if (enable) {
        TurnOnAllLights();
        SetValueOnAllLights(1);
    } else {
        TurnOffAllLights();
    }
}
```

However, this seems like a case, where I cannot avoid using `else`. The question is, is this true?

Comment: "I want this code to be clean, so I try to keep the use of if/else to a minimum." If applied mindlessly, this is a silly rule.

Comment: @PhilipKendall hence my question, to find out where the borders of this rule are. To add some mindfulness if you want :-).

Comment: You're asking the wrong question IMO. It shouldn't be "some guy in a book said `else` is not clean code, can I ignore the rule?", it should be "is this code easy to understand and maintain?"

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the book or blog that claims that else i to be avoided?

Comment: @Christophe I added two references to questions about this on this site.

Comment: Maybe a better way to express @PhilipKendall's point: it would be more productive, instead of trying to figure out where the line is for _this_ particular advice, to address why you're trying to dogmatically adhere to it in the first place. In the end, the only goal is "is this readable? Can it be better?", not "Was this `else` really necessary?". To that extent, the question you posted here focuses on the wrong approach. Even if we answer your direct question, it doesn't help with any and all other advice that you receive and dogmatically try to apply, yet the real answer is always the same.

Comment: It might be cleaner to have `LightTestOn` and `LightTestOff`.  How do callers use this?  Do they pass constants: `LightTest(true);` & `LightTest(false);` or do they pass a variable as the actual argument?

Comment: Thanks all. I have to note I do not want to dogmatically follow this rule, but just have it in my head to trigger where I can improve (clean) my code. My question is exactly about when *not* to use it. Forgive me if I have given you the impression that I blindly follow this kind of rules (I tend to not). I strive for understanding them and sites like this help me in getting a better software engineer.

Comment: @ErikEidt in the current code, they call it with constants. I do use it parametrised in my test code though.

Comment: Looking at the many constructive reactions, but also at the many readers of this question (more than 130 in a couple of hours),  I think that you hit a point of great interest !

Comment: Assuming actual production code looks like this in terms of length and complexity and naming, this is the case where you *shouldn't be bothered* about if-else at all. You have well-named methods (except for the outer one - "LightTest") that together with the if-else express clearly the intent and high level behavior of the code. It's all at the same level of abstraction, and it's not a wall of text - it's just one or two lines. It's not the if-else in itself that pollutes code, it's what you do within it (expressivenes) and with it (does it cause external coupling).

Comment: This particular case looks fine. But personally, I've always struggled to make the name of the function meaningful and correct while using booleans. If it wasn't a test, but just setting the lights on/off, would you have `SetLights(true)`? That's much less intuitive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a misleading assumption. Removing `else` statement does not make the code cleaner. It just increases the risk of mistakes.

For a detailed discussion, see for example the recommendation [MSC01-C from the CERT C secure](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MSC01-C.+Strive+for+logical+completeness) coding standard, which explains that the code should strive for logical completeness, as vulnerabilities can result when failing to consider all the possible alternatives.  In this regard, the `else` visibily demonstrates that you have considered them.

### Proof by contradiction

Let's have a look at your code, and see how you could avoid the `else`.  The systematic approach is to llok at the possible execution graphs and regorganize them to produce an equivalent graph.

A first approach is to **add a conditional for the contrary**:

```
if (enable) {
    TurnOnAllLights();
    SetValueOnAllLights(1);
} 
if (!enabled) {  // ====> OUCH ! super risky 
    TurnOffAllLights();
}
```

Rewriting the code like that removes the `else`, but it is **super risky**.  Not in your small snippet, but in real-world `if` statements, in the case where the first if-block would change the value of `enabled`, which will result in both blocks being run instead of one of the two.

A second approach is to use a **premature `return`**

```
if (enable) {
    TurnOnAllLights();
    SetValueOnAllLights(1);
    return;   // ===> HORRIBLE IN THIS CASE
} 
TurnOffAllLights();
```

It's not always bad to prematurely return.  But in this case it is it is: it requires more brainpower to understand that it's just about an alternative.  Moreover, you may [multiply unnecessarily function exit points](https://wiki.c2.com/?SingleFunctionExitPoint), which is not a very popular nor effective practice either.  Furthermore, how would you do if you'd still have a common part of code to run after the else?  Copy-paste it and repeat yourself with all the risks that it represents for the future?? This is especially tricky if this additional ode would be added later, bearing the **significant risk** of forgetting it in one of the branch.

Now the finale, the return to the **good old GOTO; really?**

```
if (enable) {
    TurnOnAllLights();
    SetValueOnAllLights(1);
    goto GREAT_SPAGHETTI_CONTINUES;
} 
TurnOffAllLights();
GREAT_SPAGHETTI_CONTINUES: // OUCH! 
//...
}
```

I'll not analyse this snippet, but just remind that it took a decade to get rid of problem-solving-by-adding-another-goto, to finally discover the virtues of [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming).  **Let's not go back to wild-goto age**.  Again, there are [cases, where the use of goto could be discussed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/334419/209774), but avoiding the `else` definitively isn't.

### If you could change more than the control flow

I cannot resist but to delegate the setting of the light to a single function:

```
TurnAllLights(enabled); // incl.responsibility for setting value correctly
```

Comment: `if (!enabled) {  // ====> OUCH ! super risky` <- not really risky, it won't compile as you've written `enabled` instead of `enable` :-)

Comment: Thanks for your lengthy explanation. About that last one, that only pushes the problem to the `TurnAllLights` method and is not a solution if you ask me.

Comment: Another popular way of removing conditionals is to [replace them with polymorphism](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) - of course, for this example, this is another approach of making the code less readable,

Comment: [Resist](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html)

Comment: @PhilipKendall you made my day ;-)

Comment: @BartFriederichs yes, sorry for the length. I took care to write the essentials in the first two paragraphs.  The proof by contradiction is more to reinsure you about the virtue of the `else`. I expected your remark on the TurnAllLights() and I guess that your real case is more complex.  I just couldn't resist ;-)

Comment: @DocBrown Indeed !  Never write an `if` if the compiler could do the work for you ;-)  It didn't mention it as the original snippet looked quite procedural and would have require some more consequent refactoring (using probably some double dispatch  between a Light and a State).

Comment: @candied_orange Excellent pointer.  It's not clear to me if `enabled` was a feature configuration or a state. I was thinking of the latter (see my comment for DocBrown).  For the former, a strategy pattern would indeed have simplified code.  Interestingly, Martin Fowler seems to have changed his mind since 2011:  he's now a promoter of the [feature flags](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html).  I guess that it's another form of "if you can't fix it, feature (toggle) it", but I have too luch respect for him, not to think that I missed some subtle differences ;-)

Comment: @Christophe [differences](https://medium.com/@amlcurran/clean-code-the-curse-of-a-boolean-parameter-c237a830b7a3)

Comment: @candied_orange ok for the refactoring. But doesn't the argument of cyclomatic complexity against `else` forget that,even without explicit `else` there is an implicit edge in the exec graph that corresponds the case where the condition is false? If I'm not mistaken, using the formula M=E-N+2P (P is 1 thanks to dead code elimination),adding an `if` increases M (1 if-node+2 edges, so M++) but adding `else` doesn't change M,since it correspond to existing second outgoing branch of the if.[Using && in condition](https://blog.feabhas.com/2018/07/code-quality-cyclomatic-complexity/) increases M more

Answer (score 0):

If it's a pure on/off scenario, a function called `toggleLights()` would be sufficient instead of turnon/turnoff.  There wouldn't be a need to pass around a boolean.  In the value for lights set value the to the inverse like:

```
x = !x;
```

That should be sufficient and there would not be a need to have a conditional.  Now if you needed to do some additional logic based on the new value of the setting, maybe then you would need a conditional to inspect that current value.

Comment: 1. If this interfaces with hardware (as OP does), the software would need to cache the value internally to allow for a `toggleLights()` function, which is not ideal (as any sort of caching can get out of sync). Looking it up can be costly, and it always complicates the calling code. 2. Quite often the functions using this API would want to set the state without caring for the previous value - in this case `toggleLights()` is also inappropriate. 3. In general, while I appreciate frame challenges, this one seems inappropriate.